"it would be" in reference to something that someone else did or does
I find conditionals quite difficult to understand in English. That's why sometimes, here or elsewhere, I quote conditional sentences written by native speakers and ask questions about them to understand how natives actually use this type of complex grammatical construction in their daily lives. So below is a quote from an answer by a native speaker on another site (link at the end):

"It helps me a lot" would be used to refer to something (an object) you use that helps you. If you took medication for pain, you might say to someone, "This medication is great, it helps me a lot."
As for "that helps me a lot" it would be in reference to something that someone else did. If someone went out of their way to provide a service that helped you, you would say, "Thanks, that helps me a lot."

As far as I know, the first sentences in the two paragraphs above are implicit second conditionals. They are followed by explicit second conditionals. As we can see, the first sentence in the first paragraph uses present simple "use" and "helps" with the conditional "would", whereas the first sentence in the second paragraph uses past simple "did" with the conditional "would".
Questions:
(1) Why did the writer prefer using present simple over past simple in the first paragraph sentence, or past simple over present simple in the second paragraph sentence? Or is it simply a mistake by the writer to use two different tenses?
(2) Can I use past simple instead of present simple in the first paragraph sentence without changing the meaning? Similarly, in the second paragraph sentence, present simple instead of past simple without changing the meaning?
https://hinative.com/questions/8646804#google_vignette

I think the writer has got their tenses a bit mixed up in the first sentence. Perhaps they use the present tense because they are thinking of 'using something that helps you' as something that is happening now, but then to be consistent they ought to have continued "If you take medication..."

...And there's an example of me getting my tenses mixed! I suppose I should have said "they ought to continue..."!

In 1 you're talking about an object which helps in past and future, in 2 you're talking about a past action. "That helps me a lot" could refer to something that someone's already done, or something in the present or future. It helps to provide more context than just your two sentences. I'm not sure "would" is the best modal verb in 1, "can" sounds better, although "would" can be present tense too.

Let's acknowledge first that conditionals are confusing. And all the taxonomy of first, second, zero, implicit, explicit et cetera is a bit artificial. These categories are "descriptive, not proscriptive"—that is, they're best as ways to help understand the statements, so don't worry too much if you have trouble deciding on the right category.
I'm going to say that the two paragraphs are the same species of conditional. In both, the writer is imagining you using a phrase. Note that both say "it would be." That is, "if you were to say this, your use of it would be like this." That's as far as we need to look for our "conditional": If you were to say this, it would be ___. Whatever follows are various imaginary scenarios, but the only imaginary scenario that matters to the categorization of the condition is the imagination of you speaking the phrase. (Note that neither one ever uses the word "if." It's implied, though: "If you were to say ___.") It also confuses things that the second sentence in each paragraph is itself a conditional, but let's ignore those to keep things simple.
The only reason we encounter different tenses after that is because the proposed phrases are different and are used in different situations. One is a general statement about how something "helps" you in general, without specific reference to one occasion. "This medicine helps me": It "is of help to me," on any given day. The other is a response to a particular occasion in which someone "helped" you. Although the writer represents you as saying "That helps me," in the present tense, there is now a specific reference to an event in the recent past: "That thing you did is 'of help to me.'" In fact the whole quote is presumably the writer's attempt to explain how you could use present tense "helps" not only to speak about the immediate present, but also about generality without a specific time, and even about the impact that past events have on the present.

(2) Can I use past simple instead of present simple in the first paragraph sentence without changing the meaning?

Not really. "A medicine I use that helps me": perhaps I take it regularly including right now, perhaps only when I need to. Regardless, its relationship to me is one of help, without needing to speak of any particular time. "A medicine I used that helped me": Now I'm clearly talking about the past. I'm not taking the medicine now, but when I did it helped.

Similarly, in the second paragraph sentence, present simple instead of past simple without changing the meaning?

Yes, actually. Once again, this isn't about the conditional; by the time we get to "... in reference to something that someone else did," the conditional "[If you were to say ___,] it would be" is done. But we could say "... it would be in reference to something that someone else does" without substantially changing the meaning. It would be a little less clear, though. Your "help" statement would be in response to the other person's action, so it must have come first, and this is made more clear by using past.

Excellent! Thanks, that helps me a lot ! You say above: we could say "... it would be in reference to something that someone else does" without substantially changing the meaning. It would be a little less clear, though. Although a little less clear, using "does" in place of "did" still refers to a specific action/ocassion, and NOT to actions in general. That is, "does" has specific reference unlike "use" and "helps" in the first paragraph sentence, which both have general reference. Am I right?
